# Compiling linux kernel for raspberry pi and /dev/video0 does not exist

Tags: raspberry-pi, linux-kernel, camera, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I am compiling linux kernel for raspberry pi and I have everything custom except linux kernel. I have my own init, own commands implementation like cat, mkdir etc. Problem is that /dev/video0 doesnot exist even though I enabled v4l2 driver etc while compiling kernel. I am using devtmpfs for creating device files.

```
(mount("devtmpfs", "/dev", "devtmpfs", 0, NULL)
```

I have many device files properly but not /dev/video0 for my CSI camera. I use raspberry pi v2.1 camera. I assume that I am missing some configuration from kernel configuration. My final point is having /dev/video0 and using v4l2 to capture a frame from a camera.

I have tried many different configurations option from kernel configuration but not success, I also have start_x=1 and gpu_mem options in config.txt file and I have required firmware files in boot folder. it boots properly but camera file does not exist.

Comment: "*I enabled v4l2 driver etc ...  I assume that I am missing some configuration*" - So what is "*etc*"? There are numerous drivers and support subsystems needed for such a complex device. "*it boots properly but camera file does not exist*" - Did you actually review the boot log for any error messages? Just because the kernel did not panic does not mean you have a "*proper*" boot. A driver could fail to initialize, and the kernel will continue to boot. A "missing" device node such as `/dev/video0` is merely the end result of a long sequence of steps that need to be checked.

Comment: I tried to enable most of the thing related with v4l2 and camera drivers under DeciveDrivers -> Multimedia drivers. About kernel error message, yes I m already observering complete boot message from kernel and there is literally NOTHING related with neither v4l2 nor camera. Probably I m missing configuration of other drivers and subsystem as you say. I have realised one thing, I dont have modprobe under /sbin folder, does kernel need moprobe, or modprobe is just for user?

Comment: scripts/config --enable CONFIG_VIDEO_DEV
scripts/config --enable CONFIG_VIDEO_V4L2
scripts/config --enable CONFIG_VIDEO_BCM2835 
scripts/config --enable CONFIG_VIDEO_V4L2_SUBDEV_API
scripts/config --enable CONFIG_MEDIA_CONTROLLER
scripts/config --enable CONFIG_VIDEO_BCM2835_UNICAM
scripts/config --enable CONFIG_VIDEO_BCM2835_ISP
scripts/config --enable CONFIG_I2C
scripts/config --enable CONFIG_I2C_BCM2835  These are commands I use in order to enable drivers.

Comment: Suggest you take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how to use this site. Learn how to [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78128009/edit) instead of putting salient information in comments and rendering them unreadable.

Comment: "*there is literally NOTHING related*" - An ambiguous statement; do you actually mean no messages from relevant drivers, or no error messages? That's why word descriptions or summations do not replace the actual data, i.e. the boot log. BTW besides a correct kernel configuration (which only "*enables*" the driver for the compilation/build phase), you also need a proper Device Tree (which describes the hardware and specifies which drivers should be initialized).